# Can I use a recursive cte to extend partitioning?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a query that I think I need recursion for. In this case, I can't quite figure out the base case and how to structure it. I have stock market data, and I want to compare moving averages ordered desc by date, and row number/ partition by the sign of the difference between two moving averages (as well as on symbol and period values as per cte). I'm using a column of 0 and 1 to help determine the partitions. With a standard partition, if a group of rows has a value of 0, then the results switch to 1 then back to 0, the 0's are all partitioned together. what I need in my result set is a new partition for each change from 0 to 1 or vice versa. I added the code as I have it now (doesn't return 2nd column, that's added to show my desired output) and some sample data I have thus far below, again with the 2nd column (RowNInner) being the column I'm trying to achieve:

```
WITH allData AS
(
    SELECT t1.Symbol, t.TradingDate AS TradeDate, t1.Period AS FastPeriod, t2.Period AS SlowPeriod, 
    t1.Value AS FastValue, t2.Value AS SlowValue, (t1.Value - t2.Value) AS SlowFastDiff,
    CASE 
        WHEN (t1.Value - t2.Value) < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS ChgSign
    FROM tblTradingDays t RIGHT JOIN tblDailySMA t1 ON t.TradingDate = t1.TradeDate JOIN tblDailySMA t2 ON 
        t1.Symbol = t2.Symbol AND t1.TradeDate = t2.TradeDate
    WHERE t1.Period < t2.Period AND t1.Symbol < 'AC'
)

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Symbol, FastPeriod, 
    SlowPeriod) AS RowNOuter, Symbol, TradeDate, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod, FastValue, SlowValue, 
    SlowFastDiff, ChgSign
FROM allData
ORDER BY Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod, TradeDate DESC, RowNInner
```

Sample result set (2nd column is what I seek):

```
RowNOuter   RowNInner     Symbol    TradeDate   FastPeriod  SlowPeriod  FastValue   SlowValue   SlowFastDiff    ChgSign
1           1             A         5/11/2012   5           10          40.05       41.166      -1.116           0
1           2             A         5/10/2012   5           10          40.362      41.477      -1.115           0
1           3             A         5/9/2012    5           10          40.856      41.702      -0.846           0
1           1             A         5/8/2012    5           10          42.018      41.78       0.238            1
1           2             A         5/7/2012    5           10          42.282      41.821      0.461            1
1           1             A         5/6/2012    5           10          41.542      41.797      -0.255           0
1           2             A         5/5/2012    5           10          41.36       41.778      -0.418           0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not missing anything, this can be solved without a recursive CTE.

The idea is as follows:

1. Rank the rows within every partition of `(Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod)` in the descending order of `TradeDate` (I guess).
2. Rank the rows within everty partition of `(Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod, ChgSign)` (again, in the descending order of `TradeDate`).
3. Find the difference between the two rankings. This will be an additional criterion for the final partitioning.
4. Now you can just rank the rows once again, partitioning them by `(Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod, ChgSign, RankDiff)`.

Here's what the resulting query might look like:

```
WITH allData AS
(
    SELECT
        t1.Symbol,
        TradeDate    = t.TradingDate,
        FastPeriod   = t1.Period,
        SlowPeriod   = t2.Period,
        FastValue    = t1.Value,
        SlowValue    = t2.Value,
        SlowFastDiff = (t1.Value - t2.Value),
        ChgSign      = CASE WHEN t1.Value < t2.Value THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM tblTradingDays t
        RIGHT JOIN tblDailySMA t1 ON t.TradingDate = t1.TradeDate
        INNER JOIN tblDailySMA t2 ON t1.Symbol     = t2.Symbol
                                 AND t1.TradeDate  = t2.TradeDate
    WHERE t1.Period < t2.Period
      AND t1.Symbol < 'AC'
)
,    partitioned AS (
    SELECT
        RowOuter = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod),
        RankDiff = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                       PARTITION BY Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod
                       ORDER BY TradeDate DESC
                   )
                 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                       PARTITION BY Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod, ChgSign
                       ORDER BY TradeDate DESC
                   ),
        Symbol,
        TradeDate,
        FastPeriod,
        SlowPeriod,
        FastValue,
        SlowValue, 
        SlowFastDiff,
        ChgSign
    FROM allData
)
SELECT
    RowOuter,
    RowInner = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod, ChgSign, RankDiff
       ORDER BY TradeDate DESC
    ),
    Symbol,
    TradeDate,
    FastPeriod,
    SlowPeriod,
    FastValue,
    SlowValue, 
    SlowFastDiff,
    ChgSign
FROM partitioned
ORDER BY Symbol, FastPeriod, SlowPeriod, TradeDate DESC, RowNInner
```